# Energy efficiency of antimatter producion

Tags: particle-physics, energy, antimatter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Matter - Antimatter Reactory Practicality](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/24832/matter-antimatter-reactory-practicality)

Certain reactions in particle accelerators lead to production of antimatter, which can then be collected in noticeable quantities and potentially used for spacecraft propulsion, bombs, etc.

My questions:

- What is [roughly estimated] energy efficiency of antimatter production? That is, how much energy is needed to produce e.g. anti-hydrogen of mass *m*, compared to 2 *mc²* (we suppose that plain matter is free)?
- Is there an obvious reason why this efficiency can (or cannot) be made significantly higher than 1?

Comment: "which can then be collected in noticeable quantities and potentially used for spacecraft propulsion, bombs, etc." -- I think I saw that movie.

Comment: Energy is conserved, so you'll never get back more than what you put in.

Comment: Note that at this time "collecting" the anti-matter from accelerator interactions is difficult and very inefficient. But it gets worse: it can be stored on macroscopic time scales only at low density, with more difficulty, and at the cost of much more energy.

Comment: @MattReece: energy _and mass_ are conserved together. I'd like to differentiate them here. E.g. how much electrical energy is needed to operate an accelerator for production of 1 mcg of anti-hydrogen? (Not how many grams of uranium will be spent for it on a power plant, etc.)

Comment: As of movies: [antimatter is produced in measurable quantities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antimatter#Artificial_production), [NASA used to consider it for propulsion](http://www.nasa.gov/exploration/home/antimatter_spaceship.html).

Comment: Also, even if you could get antimatter stored in considerable quantities, with efficiency close to 1 (not bigger). What would you do with it? Eletron-positron pairs anihilate into 500 keV  gamma rays, which is very bad for propulsion. Photons this hard can´t just be reflected for push. You would have to find materials that would absorb and thermalize them, and then eject these. I don't think this is much better than what we already do, at much higher costs.

Comment: @9000 (3 comments up): this is all explained in the linked duplicate question, but the short answer to your question is: the energy required is always necessarily more than $(\text{2 mcg})c^2$. (assuming by mcg you mean some unit of mass) For an accelerator, it will be many billions or trillions of times more.

Comment: @DavidZaslavsky: Yes, mcg = microgram. I don't assume that the _whole_ mass of the antimatter must be created from incoming energy. I thought that most of it could come from matter somehow. Is this possible? If not, the answer is obvious.

Comment: @9000: I'd have to think about it to be 100% sure, but I don't believe that's possible.